# How to display multiple JSON values in full calendar?

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am currently displaying a single JSON object value in the full calendar. I need to display the second JSON object as well.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var booking_details  = @json($booking_details);

    // I need to display these json values also
    var test  = @json($test);
    

    $("#calander").fullCalendar({
      events: booking_details,
      eventColor: '#FF0000'
    }); 
});
</script>
```

This is the controller in Laravel:

```
$booking_details = array();
$bookings = Booking::all();
   
foreach ($bookings as $booking) {

    $booking_details[] = [
       'title'=>$booking->room_number,
       'start'=>$booking->checkin_date,
       'end'=>$booking->checkout_date
    ];
}

// this is testing purpose
$test = array();

foreach ($bookings as $booking) {
   $test[] = [
       'title'=>$booking->room_number,
       'start'=>$booking->checkin_date,
       'end'=>$booking->checkout_date
   ];
}
```

I'm sending the same data with a different JSON name. I only need how to display multiple JSON object values in the same calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just add all the data to the `$booking_details` array in the PHP code? But also, `$test` just contains the exact same data as booking_details, so what's the point? Maybe that's just a poor example in the question, I can't tell?

But anyway if you have two separate sources of data you want to supply as events, you can either

1. use one array in PHP as I suggested above, or
2. concatenate them in JavaScript as IT goldman's answer shows, or
3. you can have them as two separate event feeds, which you can set up in fullCalendar via the [eventSources](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventSources) option, e.g.

```
$("#calander").fullCalendar({
  eventSources: [
    {
      "events": booking_details,
      "color": "red"
    },
    {
      "events": test,
      "color": "blue"
    }
  ],
});
```

Comment: thank you. you solved my problem. can you please tell how to add seperate color for two sources like booking_details=red
    test=blue like that.

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-source-object) you can set the `color` property on an event source. I will update the answer slightly. But in future please specify all your requirements up-front in the question, rather than asking them one by one. (Unless they are very big or unrelated requirements of course, in which case they should be separate questions :-))

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to add the two arrays of events.

```
$("#calander").fullCalendar({
    events: booking_details.concat(test),
    eventColor: '#FF0000'
});
```